# Efficient method to append only the new rows from pandas dataframe to a table in database

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a table `X` in MySQL as follows

```
A   B
1   2
3   4
5   6
```

and I have a dataframe `df` as follows

```
A   B
1   2
5   6
7   8
9  10
```

I want to append to `X` only new rows from `df` (rows that are in `df` but not in `X`).  The results should be:

```
A   B
1   2
3   4
5   6
7   8
9  10
```

Note that sorting does not matter for me.  Currently, what I can do are

```
1. Read table X and store in a dataframe called dfx
2. Concat df and dfx 
3. Drop duplicate rows
4. Insert the results back to the table X with to_sql(if_exist='replace')
```

However, I think this is not a good practice particularly when the table X is very large.  May I have your suggestions for the better way?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a unique index in your table that would prevent you to insert duplicate records (the primary key should do the job), then using `INSERT IGNORE`instead of `INSERT` will be enough: duplicate records will be silently discarded instead of generating an error.

Answer (score 0):

If your indices are unique (or one of the columns, say A), you could

1. make a list of indices (or the unique column) from the dataframe,
2. query MySQL with the list and find the ones that do not exist in the table,
3. subset the dataframe based on the new indices or column values, and insert.

You will have to use something like `sqlalchemy` for (2).  (3) can be done easily by using `DataFrame.query`; e.g. `df.query("A == @list_of_new_values")`, where `list_of_new_values` is a python list with the new values for column A.